# Trigger for tabcontainer asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, aspx-user-control

I have a ajax `tabcontainer` (web-forms not MVC) with different tabs and i have a radio-button list on one of them and when I click on it a value on a different tab needs to change.

Whats the best approach for a trigger here?

Comment: Well i just took over a program at work and its not built that way, its using as i said Ajax tabcontrol and the values ar set on the server side. And i cant rebuild the whole application

Comment: i think you'll need to use 'FindControl' (Page.FindControl maybe), possibly a very long statement to find the right control.